# Openlayers on Android and chrome browser - white lines when using viewport meta tag

Tags: android, google-chrome, openlayers

When rendering TMS tiles, sometimes there is a white line that shows up between tiles. Not between all tiles, just some, and only sometimes. Pan around and it disappears and reappears again.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lm13J.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/izWy1.jpg

This is using OpenLayers 2.12 (non-mobile) version. Only happening on Android (tested on 4+ Galaxy Tab2), and only in the Chrome browser. Native browser is fine. I do specify this tag:

So pretty standard viewport tag. If the tag is not specified, no white line. I do need the tag to display the content at scale=1.0 only without the scalability option.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,

Andre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never found an answer to this question. It does seem that the Android Chrome browser, if you set the viewport to scale=1.0, on some devices interprets it as a 'zoom' of the viewport. So just like Ctrl+mouse wheel zoom in desktop browser.

What is interesting, if you do that in Chrome in google maps - you will also see white lines between tiles sometimes.

So - tough luck. Chrome.